# How do I prevent cursor from being unclipped?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm trying to keep my cursor clipped to the window when the active window is a specific application.  I have the following whenever the `WinEventHook` raises the event for a context change:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ClipCursor(ref RECT lpRect);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ClipCursor(IntPtr zero);

    private void ProcessEvent(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        var windowName = GetActiveWindowTitle(hwnd);
        if (windowName == "Application Window Title")
        {
            RECT rect;
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect);
            ClipCursor(ref rect);
        }
        else
        {
            ClipCursor(IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
```

I can confirm that `ClipCursor` does work, but it seems that whenever I click or do something within my application, the clipping just stops working and I can move my mouse outside of the bounds of the window again.  I've put it through the debugger and confirmed that `rect` has the correct values every time, but only the first call to `ClipCursor` works.

I began to suspect that something else is causing my cursor to become unclipped after the initial call to `ClipCursor()` since if I do

```
while(true) ProcessEvent(GetForegroundWindow());
```

the issue with the cursor becoming unclipped disappears.  However, this obviously introduces a problem that I'm just eating up CPU cycles to get this to work correctly.  How can I detect when the unclipping occurs so that I can make this more efficient?